# modelsim10.4SE install problem on windows10

Tags: installation, fpga, modelsim

when i install modelsim10.4SE in my windows10 completed. but when run modelsim there comes an error.could sameone help me ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUC47.png)

Comment: This might be better suited to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: ok, but i'm a don't konw how to use stack overflow. and superuser need 300 reputation.

Comment: Well you can learn to use Stack Overflow by going through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and looking through the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). I'm not aware of a reputation requirement on superuser as I've posted a question on the site with less than 300 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The first Modelsim 10.4 version was released back in 2014 and had no Windows 10 support, perhaps more importantly it also didn't support Windows 8.1 yet, so I think you simply stumbled upon a Windows compatibility issue.

Try to run Modelsim (vsim/vcom/vlib/etc) in Windows7/8 compatibility mode, try the 32bits version or if you have the license install a later version of Modelsim SE.

Good luck,
Hans.

Comment: but a friend of mine have the same computer and windows version of me. and he had installed the same version modelsim and run well.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, but I've encountered the same issue and I think that I've found a way to solve it.
In my case another program was blocking the install (Skype/lync). After closing it the installation wizard kicked in as it was supposed to do.
To find the program that was causing the issue I used the new option added to the task manager called "Analize wait chain" and eventually got to lync.

Comment: What should I do with the "analyze wait chain" if I can't even find the executable? After I click the installer it just shows "unpacking" then disappears.